# GCP - deploy automatically AppEngine having cron job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

I am struggling. I can't find a solution for this issue.

I want to set a CloudBuild config file *'cloudbuild-preprod.yaml'* that deploys the app and then deploy the cron job every time I merge with a specific branch on git.

The deployment works fine. But When I wanted to add a second job to automate deployment of the cron job. GCP throws an error.

Here's my cloudbuild file *'cloudbuild-preprod.yaml'*

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", 'app/compa-api-notifications-preprod.yaml']
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", 'app/cron-preprod.yaml']
timeout: '1200s'
```

Here's my cron config file '*cron-preprod.yaml*':

```
cron:
- description: "monthly summary estimations"
  url: /v1/sendMailEstimationsReminders
  schedule: 1 of month 09:00
  retry_parameters:
    job_retry_limit: 1
```

And finally Here's my config file '*compa-api-notifications-preprod.yaml*' (This works fine without the cron job).

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
service: compa-notifications
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

When Triggered, The first Job works fine but the second job throws an error:

```
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 1
ERROR
Finished Step #1
Step #1:   in "/workspace/app/cron-preprod.yaml", line 2, column 1
Step #1: Unexpected attribute 'cron' for object of type AppInfoExternal.
Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [/workspace/app/cron-preprod.yaml]
Step #1: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Starting Step #1
```

any help would be appreciated ! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

I finally Got it working by just renaming the cron config file from **cron-preprod.yaml** to **cron.yaml**. GCP won't understand it's a cron config file if it is not named cron.yaml.

Comment: If you want to avoid one more element to be maintained on your pipeline, you can use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) in this case